# incorrect character rendered in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

[image]

The HTML is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,300,400,700);
        h1 {
            font-family: 'Open sans',sans-serif;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Tām rō̜i ʻĀthit ʻUthai Rātsadō̜n</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

The bottom is Firefox 103.0.2 and top is Chrome 104.0.5112.79. (Running macOS Monterey 12.5)

When I change the `font-weight` from `300` to `400` (or more), Chrome starts displaying everything correctly. Not sure what the issue is.

Rendered Fonts section of Chrome (right) and Firefox (left).
[image]

Comment: it's best to use [html entities](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html) for special characters

Comment: could it be a font issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that your language is not supported with utf-8 encoding, so check this out here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=globalization-supported-languages-locales.

also: better to import your data via url() as string, I mean replace

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,300,400,700);
```

with

```
 @import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,300,400,700");
```

Comment: When I have had very simmilar situation the solution was to add 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: Off: Utf8 can encode any Unicode characters up to U+10FFFF, that doesn't depend on language. (Actually, Utf8 could encode characters up to 7FFFFFFF (using 1-6 byte long sequences),  but it has been restricted by RFC3629 to be utf16-compatible)